# How to get the source code of an application created with native react from the APK file?

Tags: 18.04, source-code

I'm trying to get the source code of an application to study its operation and try to make my version of the same APP from scratch.
I have seen several ways but none of them worked on Ubuntu 18.04.
I've tried it more times was a response found in stackoverflow, of which I show the link below, but in STEP-2, section 4, I can not get the necessary file created.
Is there any way in Ubuntu to achieve my purpose?
Thank you.

Link to the question why I have been guided:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Comment: It is not exactly clear what the problem is "in STEP-2, section 4". What is the "necessary file" you want to be created? Have you run the specified command?

Comment: The following command is the one that does not work: ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex @mikewhatever,  does not generate the classes.dex.dex2jar file

Comment: Have you seen the comments under the accepted answer? Some recommend downloading another file, if stuck at 2.4.